# Disable unpickling, but allow everything else

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using a 3rd party library that has an unfortunate tendency to use pickles unless directed otherwise.

I know that loading a pickle may allow arbitrary code execution, so I would like to know when the library attemps to do this.

What can I do to stop it from unpickling?

Here's my attempt:

```py
class Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def load(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("Unpickling is disabled in this script.")
    
def load(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise RuntimeError("Unpickling is disabled in this script.")
    
def loads(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise RuntimeError("Unpickling is disabled in this script.")
    
pickle.Unpickler = Unpickler
pickle.load = load
pickle.loads = loads

import pickle_fanatic_library
```

Is this good enough to disallow arbitrary code execution?

(I would like to keep as many features from `pickle` as possible)